# Why is UnknownHostException not caught in Exception (java)?

Tags: java, exception

My code looks like this :

```
try
{
   String htmlPageText=readFromHtml("http://www.yahoo.com");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  System.out.println("===Here===");
}
```

Method `readFromHtml()` will take a URL and return an HTML page. Normally it works fine. But I'm trying to simulate a "site down" situation, so I unplugged the Internet connection. I thought, the error should be caught and the result will be "===Here===", but instead, it returned:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: http://www.yahoo.com"
```

and never printed out "===Here===". `UnknownHostException` is an extension of `java.lang.Exception`, so why was it not caught in the catch clause? Do I need a catch `(UnknownHostException ex)` to get it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have posted.  I suspect the problem lies in the readFromHtml method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the readFromHTML method source code ? My guess is that this method throws some kind of exception but not UnknownHostException... Somewhere else in your code the exception is left unhandled.

Comment: Great "catch", you got it ! I looked into it and it has this : "catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }" in it. Thanks !

Comment: I wrote something not very accurate then. The exception was actually _handled_ somewhere else :) It would be good if you edit your answer with the code of the method, for future bypassers.